# Write image file in servlet by using ImageIO

Tags: java, servlets, javax.imageio

I am generating an image in my servlet:

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,"jpg" ,Outputstream)
```

But after deploying I am receiving an error that it can't read the input file.

Comment: You need to provide more information, what is the exception ? , How do you read file

Comment: How are you accessing the file?  That might give us a hint as to what you're doing wrong...

Comment: Please, you must add much more detail to your question. Show us your exact code. What is the exact error message?

Comment: File f = new File(pathToWeb +"/"+ "check.jpg"); BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f); ImageIO.read(f); OutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream(); ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", out1); i am using above code but while using .write method system is throwing an error that not able to read the inputed file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time ago I wrote the following code (it was taking the image stored as blob in database and writing it to the servler output):

```
public class ImageDB extends HttpServlet {
// ...
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 // ...
byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes((long)1, (int)blob.length());

ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(bytes);
out.close(); // Close stream
// ...

  }


}
```

Comment: File f = new File(pathToWeb +"/"+ "check.jpg");
 BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
 ImageIO.read(f);
 OutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream();
 ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", out1); i am using above code but while using .write method system is throwing an error that  not able to read the inputed file